# SQLAlchemy - Issue w/ func.lower

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm working on a flask app that leverages SQLAlchemy. I updated my app to point to a PostgresQL db but I'm getting hung up on a small but important piece of code:

```
records = Record.query.filter(func.lower(Record.name.like('{}%'.format(point)))).all()
```

In the past this ran without issue. Now that I'm using Postgres and psycopg2 I'm getting the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) function lower(boolean) does not exist

LINE 3: WHERE lower(record.name LIKE 'a%')
              ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
 [SQL: 'SELECT record.id, record.name
        FROM record
        WHERE lower(record.name LIKE %(name_1)s)'] [parameters: {'name_1': 'a%'}]
```

I'm new to flask and web apps but my understanding that using an ORM means that I should be able to swap out databases relatively easily and that all existing code should run without issue.

Note: `x = Record.query.order_by(func.lower(Record.name)).all()` runs without issues

Comment: `WHERE lower(record.name) LIKE 'a%'` or `WHERE record.name ILIKE 'a%'` (ILIKE is case insensitive LIKE, so no need for a lower() call)

Comment: `WHERE lower(record.name) LIKE 'a%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIKE` is case-sensitive, `ILIKE` is case-insensitive.

With `ILIKE` You don't need to use `lower`.

```
records = record.query.filter(Record.name.ilike('{}%'.format(point))).all()
```